# Animate with OpenGL, compute with CUDA

Tags: opengl, cuda, interop

I've written a CUDA Random Walk simulation. I.e. I have two vectors X and Y containing the position of all the particles I simulate. During each timestep I update their position according to my computation.

```
/* Calculate velocity magnitude */
CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateNormal(gen, dev_v, Nrand,0,1.0));
/* Generate direction on device */
CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, dev_alpha, Nrand));
/* X_t+1 = X_t + V */
scosaxpy<<<blocksPerGrid,threadsPerBlock>>>(Nrand,dev_alpha,dev_v,dev_x);
ssinaxpy<<<blocksPerGrid,threadsPerBlock>>>(Nrand,dev_alpha,dev_v,dev_y);
```

Where `sscosaxpy()` updates my position as `x+=cos(alpha)*vx`. My code is then structured as

```
/* initilize memory */
/* set up CURAND */

for(t=0;t<T;t++){
   /* calculate velocity magnitude and direction */
   /* update position */
   /* eventually copy memory to host */
}
```

Now comes the part, where I have no background in. Visualizing with OpenGL. I have looked up some examples (NVIDIA also provides some examples for the interaction between CUDA and OpenGL), but most of them are either to complex, or don't handle the case where the computation is done by CUDA.

My Question: Can anybody give me the steps to visualize my output in the following way

```
for(t=0;t<T;t++){
   /* calculate velocity magnitude and direction */
   /* update position */
   /* eventually copy memory to host */

   /* Update the position of my particles in a 2D plot */
}
```

Could you provide a complete working example?

Comment: Do you need to visualize your ouput? Why isnt it enough to write into text file and check whether output is correct?

Comment: I'm also writing the data to file, but for a better understanding I would like to visualize the results. I also fail to understand why this post was downvoted. Could you explain that please?

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question but those who did may not like the fact you are asking them to do your work :) There is a plenty of OpenGL tutorials so you have no "real" obstacles yet in getting this done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this in OpenGL. They vary on complexity and performance. Since you're using CUDA I believe that you'd like your visualization to run quite fast. This is a bit more complex than just rendering those points without thinking about performance. If you have no previous OpenGL experience i suggest using the most straightforward solution where you draw one point at the time. Take a look at this tutorial (It's just an example. You can try any tutorial that has a working code): http://openglsamples.sourceforge.net/triangle.html

Try to run it and see a triangle. Now find a display() function and see that the code responsible for drawing is placed between glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); and glEnd();

You will need to modify it, since you don't want to draw triangles. Instead here's what you should do. After the CUDA step I'm expecting you to have an array of 3D points.

```
for(t=0;t<T;t++){
   /* calculate velocity magnitude and direction */
   /* update position */
   /* eventually copy memory to host */
}

/* Now your points are stored in an array. Let's say float particles[T][3]; */
/* Update the position of my particles in a 2D plot */
display();
```

You should modify the display() part that I've already mentioned like that:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int t=0;i<T;t++)
    {
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);  //In case you want to give them unique colors in future     
        glVertex3f( particles[t][0], particles[t][1], particles[t][2]);
    }                               
glEnd();
```

Now you should see your particles. If the number T is relatively high the rendering may be slow, but just to picture where your particles are located it should be enough. Keep in mind, that positions of your particles have to be in the view angle of your camera which in that cas is located in point (0,0,3) and looks in the negative direction of Z axis having 45 degrees of view angle.